# I want to use jenkins to build iphone project from github,but find some bugs

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

```
Going to invoke xcodebuild:, scheme: testgit, sdk: iphoneos8.4, project: testgit.xcodeproj, configuration: Release, clean: YES, archive:NO, symRoot: DEFAULT, configurationBuildDir: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/test12345/build, codeSignIdentity: DEFAULT
[test12345] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme testgit -sdk iphoneos8.4 -project testgit.xcodeproj -configuration Release clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/test12345/build
Build settings from command line:
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/test12345/build
SDKROOT = iphoneos8.4

xcodebuild: error: The project 'testgit' does not contain a scheme named 'testgit'.
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Sending e-mails to: ww1095@163.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.4'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      2 errored, 0 warning (292 ms)
new BUG!!!!

Comment: I have find answer
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20916

Answer (score 0):

I'd try by marking the scheme 'testgit' as shared in Xcode.. Navigate to Product->Scheme->Manage Scheme

[image: Product->Scheme-]

[image: Mark your scheme as shared]